# Update Dataframe on the basis of subset dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, of which one is the subset of other.
ex:

```
data1 = [{'account': 'abc_test', 'value': 100, 'acc_id': '11'},
        {'account': 'def_test', 'value': 50, 'acc_id': '12'}, 
        {'account': 'ghi_badbad', 'value': 25, 'acc_id': '13'},
        {'account': 'hso', 'value': 22, 'acc_id': '14'},
        {'account': 'mko', 'value': 47.5, 'acc_id': '15'}]

data2 = [{'account': 'ghi_badbad', 'value': 25, 'acc_id': '13'},
         {'account': 'mko', 'value': 47.5, 'acc_id': '15'}]
```

Column acc_id is the index in both.

**We need to update the value of account in data1 with respect to the values of acc_id in data2.**

Options I tried: **Merging**

```
dfx = pd.merge(df1, df2, indicator=True, how='outer', on='acc_id')
dfx.loc[dfx['_merge'] == 'both', 'account_x'] = 'xxx'
```

then I am getting output column names with _x and _y

```
  account_x  value_x acc_id   account_y  value_y     _merge
0  abc_test    100.0     11         NaN      NaN  left_only
1  def_test     50.0     12         NaN      NaN  left_only
2       xxx     25.0     13  ghi_badbad     25.0       both
3       hso     22.0     14         NaN      NaN  left_only
4       xxx     47.5     15         mko     47.5       both
```

I need output like this:

```
    account  value acc_id
0  abc_test  100.0     11
1  def_test   50.0     12
2       xxx   25.0     13
3       hso   22.0     14
4       xxx   47.5     15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need test only one column [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) is your friend:

```
df1.loc[df1['acc_id'].isin(df2['acc_id']), 'account'] = 'xxx'
print (df1)
    account  value acc_id
0  abc_test  100.0     11
1  def_test   50.0     12
2       xxx   25.0     13
3       hso   22.0     14
4       xxx   47.5     15
```

Your solution is better, if need test match by mutiple columns - only use left join and filter columns used for join:

```
dfx = pd.merge(df1, df2[['acc_id']], indicator=True, how='left', on='acc_id')

#match by multiple columns
#dfx = pd.merge(df1, df2[['acc_id', 'another_id']], indicator=True, how='left', on=['acc_id', 'another_id'])

dfx.loc[dfx.pop('_merge') == 'both', 'account'] = 'xxx'
print (dfx)
    account  value acc_id
0  abc_test  100.0     11
1  def_test   50.0     12
2       xxx   25.0     13
3       hso   22.0     14
4       xxx   47.5     15
```